# is there an 'anti-step' for a python range? range(0, 100, n) gives me every nth number, what if i want to exclude every nth number?

Tags: python, range

how can I exclude numbers from a range without creating a giant list?

How would I get all the numbers from 1, 100,  for example, but exclude every nth number?

And what about with multiple n's? Exclude every 3rd and every 11th number, for example.

What's the best way to do this?

It's easy to do with if statements and appending to a list, but that becomes useless for any range of a large size, because I don't want a list with a million items.

basically I have a very large range of numbers and i want to exclude those which are divisible by 3.

using an if statement and checking %3 for every single number is also really inefficient

everything seems so simple in python that it seems I should be able to just skip every 3rd number, but much googling has left me without an answer.

is there no easy, efficient way to do this?

Comment: What behaviour do you need? If it's just the stream of values, make an _iterator_, `filter` or `itertools.filterfalse` the appropriate values.

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose the call to range in a generator expression, and apply a filter to the not-wanted numbers, using an expression with the modulo-operator.

```
for number in (number in range(10) if number % 3):
    ...
```

If you need getitem and containmentship testing, make it a list comprehension instead:

`numbers = [number in range(10) if number % 3]`

Note that a generator expression is a shortcut for creating a generator - if more complex rules are needed, one may at any time create a generator function  - a function that yields results, and can be used directly in `for` statements and wherever an iterator is wanted.

```
def myrange(start, stop, step, antistep=None):
    for item in range(start, stop, step):
         if item % antistep == 0:  # or any other expression
             continue  # just skip this item
         yield item


for count in myrange(0, 100, 5):
    ...
```

Comment: You probably meant `(number for number in range(10) if number % 3)`

Comment: Because `number in range(10)` is not a compound iteration. `number for number in range(10)` is. And, secondly `if not number%3` filter those that are multiple of 3 only. Since `number%3` is truthy when number is NOT multiple of 3.

Comment: yes, yes - I fixed it already.

Comment: You corrected the second one. But not the first one. `numbers = [number in range(10) if not number % 3]` is a syntax error (one that I often make). `numbers=[number for number in range(10) if not number%3]` is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar, in spirit, to generating all the values and then filtering out the numbers you don't want, but you can use numpy to do this quite efficiently

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> values = np.arange(100)
>>> values[values % 3 != 0]
array([ 1,  2,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25,
       26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50,
       52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 71, 73, 74, 76,
       77, 79, 80, 82, 83, 85, 86, 88, 89, 91, 92, 94, 95, 97, 98])
```

Comment: But the OP wanted to avoid huge list creation. If you want to compute the sum of all numbers below 1 billion that are not multiples of 3, on my computer, it crashes because of OOM. With a simple `sum(x for x in range(1000000000) if x%3)` I get the result in a few dozen of seconds, without any visible usage of memory. (Ok, for that example, you may say, I could have computed `1000000000*1000000001//2 - 3*(333333333*333333334//2)` to use even less memory and compute even faster. But you get the idea.

Comment: @chrslg I'm not sure I believe they would give the same results. Removing 1/3 of the potential results doesn't drop you from OOM to "without visible memory use". Even if you have a generator - you're still accumulating into a list

Comment: What you potentially did was establish a generator. That's low memory. It just never got consumed for the result

Comment: I am 100% sure your code gives the exact same result as mine. That is not the point. Simply, with 1000000000, my computer won't live to see your code giving to correct result, because of all the memory needed for the numpy array. While, as you said, the generator use no memory. Your last comment is my point. Surely, if we call `list(thegenerator)` at the end, it would probably OOM too. My point was not about the 1/3 less items in the list. But in my example (computing the sum) we never store thing nowhere with general, while we do with your np.array based solution.

Comment: This is not a virtual comment. I really have tried both method. I really nearly crashed my computer running yours (and crashed python process, which saved the computer). And I really computed the sum of the 1 billion first numbers that are not factor of 3 in a few dozen seconds. And all that while monitoring memory usage. I was not just speculating. Anyway, I am sure you don't need to be convinced that in the case of "sum", iterating the generator need just a few bytes to store the generator state. So, again, that was my point, not the 1/3 less values.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward to wrap this up in a function you can reuse flexibly.

```
>>> def skip(start, end, pred):
...   yield from (x for x in range(start, end) if not pred(x))
... 
>>> list(skip(1, 100, lambda x: x % 3 == 0))
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 71, 73, 74, 76, 77, 79, 80, 82, 83, 85, 86, 88, 89, 91, 92, 94, 95, 97, 98]
>>> for x in skip(1, 100, lambda a: a % 3 == 0):
...   print(x, end=' ')
... 
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 16 17 19 20 22 23 25 26 28 29 31 32 34 35 37 38 40 41 43 44 46 47 49 50 52 53 55 56 58 59 61 62 64 65 67 68 70 71 73 74 76 77 79 80 82 83 85 86 88 89 91 92 94 95 97 98
```